# Is possible to use cookie based authentication with ASP.NET Web API and SPA?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, cookies

I want to create the web application which will be based on angularjs frontend and ASP.NET Web API. I need create the secure api but I can't use the token based authentication on the company's server where will be implemented this web application.

Is possible use the cookie based authentication for SPA and ASP.NET Web API?

How can I configure the cookie based authentication on the ASP.NET project for this scenario where I have the SPA and Web API?

Comment: Even tokens are stored in cookies, it is the most common way to maintain a session.

Comment: @JahirulIslamBhuiyan Isn't it ironic that this question is the #1 google result? Your comment didn't help me at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The TokenBased Authentication is currently used in SPA based on BackEnd API applications is to overcome the limitation of cookiebased authentication But since you have decided to go with it then you can use **OWIN** cookieAuthentication middleware which will do the needful. [Here's an article showing how to configure](https://brockallen.com/2013/10/24/a-primer-on-owin-cookie-authentication-middleware-for-the-asp-net-developer/) the OWIN cookie authentication middleware in Asp.net project(No matter if it's WebApi or MVC application).

Comment: Can we use cookie based authentication if SPA and ASP.NET Web API are different projects and are on different domains? I have multiple clients,  Will I be able to use only bearer token in this case?

Comment: too me the Token Authentication look fulls of limit and hardness ship :|
also it look buggy and requires lots of efforts which i'm not aware of...