# How to get webforms signed in user in Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have ASP.NET webforms app. This app uses cookie-based authentication. Also I have ASP.NET Web API that receives AJAX requests from webforms app. What i'd like to do is have possibility in controller's actions know if request comes from authenticated user and  get user id.
I don't have much experience in web development.
Could you advice some good approach to accomplish this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think most suitable way is to use OWIN cookieAuthentication middleware.
It is described here [Is possible to use cookie based authentication with ASP.NET Web API and SPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37217705/is-possible-to-use-cookie-based-authentication-with-asp-net-web-api-and-spa)

Answer (score 0):

You should first secure your API using a STS (security token service) such as IdentityServer3 or 4 ... and then on login, get a token to access the APIs. This token can contain user identity information as well as resource access permissions. Lookup OAuth2 and IdentityServer4 here ... http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/

Comment: Thanks. Does my cookie-based authentication system in webforms application need to be changed in this case?

Comment: I will appreciate also any other ideas